# VIM colors not right

Tags: vim, gvim

I have a gvim setup on Windows and am also running a vim installation on CentOS in a VirtualBox VM.

I'm trying to get it where they both share the same colorscheme.

I believe in the Linux .vim files, I should use the terms termfg, termbg and term while in the gvim's .vim files, I should use guifg, guibg, and gui.

Is this correct? I ask this because I took the same .vim file from Windows gvim, copied it to the CentOs VM, changed the terms above and don't get the same visual when opening the file shown in this screenshots below.

***GVIM, The way I want it***
[image]

***VIM, Not even close***

[image]
Yes, I ran the command `colorscheme vs`, my 'theme' is named 'vs'.
If I use same .vim file, I get the output above, If I change the terms like I noted above, I get errors along the lines of
`Color name or number not recognized: ctermfg=#c0d0e0`

Can anyone help out here?

Here is the contents of my .vim file for gvim, For Linux, I removed the last line:

```
set background=light

hi clear
if exists("syntax_on")
  syntax reset
endif

let colors_name = "vs"

" Taglist colors
hi MyTagListFileName    guifg=black   guibg=#c0d0e0
hi MyTagListTagName     guifg=black   guibg=#00ff00

hi CursorLine     guibg=#f6f6f6
hi CursorColumn   guibg=#f6f6f6   guibg=white
hi MatchParen     guifg=black     guibg=#CCE0DB

hi TabLine        guifg=black     guibg=#b0b8c0
hi TabLineFill    guifg=#9098a0
hi TabLineSel     guifg=black     guibg=#f0f0f0 gui=bold

hi Pmenu          guifg=white     guibg=#808080
hi PmenuSel       guifg=black     guibg=#ffbc29

hi Title        guifg=#202020   gui=none
hi Underlined   guifg=#202020   gui=underline

hi Normal       guifg=black     guibg=white
hi ModeMsg      guifg=black     guibg=white
hi Cursor       guifg=black     guibg=white     gui=underline
hi LineNr       guifg=#ffffff   guibg=#c0d0e0
hi Visual                       guibg=#8ABDF0
hi WildMenu     guifg=black     guibg=#ffbc29
hi IncSearch    guibg=black     guifg=#ffbc29
hi Question     guifg=black     guibg=#ffbc29

hi StatusLine   guifg=white     guibg=black   gui=bold
hi StatusLineNC guifg=white     guibg=#8090a0 gui=bold
hi VertSplit    guifg=#a0b0c0   guibg=#a0b0c0 gui=none

hi NonText      guifg=black     guibg=#ffffff
hi Comment      guifg=#008000   gui=none
hi Folded       guifg=#E8DDD7   guibg=#FAF7F6
hi Folded       guifg=#708090   guibg=#c0d0e0
hi FoldColumn   guifg=#708090   guibg=#c0d0e0

hi Constant     guifg=#6f008a   gui=none
hi Number       guifg=blue
hi Float        guifg=blue
hi Boolean      guifg=black     gui=none
hi String       guifg=red       gui=none

hi Statement    guifg=blue      gui=none
hi StorageClass guifg=blue      gui=none
hi Type         guifg=blue      gui=none
hi Typedef      guifg=blue      gui=none
hi Structure    guifg=blue      gui=none
hi Identifier   guifg=black     gui=none
hi Function     guifg=blue      gui=none
hi Repeat       guifg=blue      gui=none
hi Conditional  guifg=black     gui=none
hi Operator     guifg=black     gui=none

hi PreProc      guifg=blue      gui=none
hi Define       guifg=blue      gui=none
hi Include      guifg=blue      gui=none

hi Error        guifg=red       guibg=#f2f2f2   gui=bold,underline
hi Todo         guifg=yellow    guibg=yellow    gui=none
hi Search       guifg=black     guibg=yellow    gui=none
hi SpecialKey   guifg=#1060a0   guibg=#f2f2f2
hi Special      guifg=black     guibg=#ffffff

" Diff
hi DiffChange   guifg=NONE      guibg=#e0e0e0   gui=bold
hi DiffText     guifg=NONE      guibg=#f0c8c8   gui=bold
hi DiffAdd      guifg=NONE      guibg=#c0e0d0   gui=bold
hi DiffDelete   guifg=NONE      guibg=#f0e0b0   gui=bold

set guifont="Consolas for Powerline":h10
```

Comment: Well, looks like I was wrong, you only set those terms for terminal output. But that still doesn't explain why the colors are incorrect on the CentOS version when I use the same files.